# Big Data vs Relational Database on making structure of Data-ware house for telecom data analysis

Tags: data-warehouse, rdbms

I'm currently doing my final year project on telecommunication mining. On starting project I got confuse on choosing database. As data on mobile communication is going on increasing so I think Big data is useful on reducing time complexity of the project. But I stuck my head on finding better option. I had no experience on Big Data except its general concept but I'm quit familiar with relational database (oracle).

So my question is:- Which data will be best option on doing such project and why? So I appreciate any suggestion regarding the database selection and design.

> Project Background:-
>   We have 100's of thousand of data of call details of customer along with their personal information and we have to perform various mining technique for pattern analysis.

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't an answerable question currently. Aside from which, 100's of thousands/millions of rows is pocket change and doesn't remotely fit into the buzzword category of "big data". You would however be welcome to pop into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) to seek opinion and/or flesh out a better question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule of Thumb: Does your workload fit with "traditional" approaches? Like oracle? Oracle can handle "00's of thousand of data of call" so does other databases like MySQL and SQL Server. You start looking into "Big Data Tools" when these solutions start to break. It's a pretty old video but it has some good insights: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5keh0UU0mNo

Also I like the answer by Jeff Hammerbacher asnwer to similar question. Start at 27:01 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVxc9lhMA0M

You could also consider reading the book "Planning for Big data" (free)
http://parasdoshi.com/2012/05/18/want-to-learn-about-bigdata-read-oreillys-book-planning-for-bigdata/